# Access input from UIAlertController

Tags: swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

I've got a UIAlertController which is prompted to the user when they choose "Enter Password" on the TouchID screen. How do I recover the user's input after presenting this on screen?

```
let passwordPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Password", message: "You have selected to enter your passwod.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
passwordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
passwordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

passwordPrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
                        textField.placeholder = "Password"
                        textField.secureTextEntry = true
                        })

presentViewController(passwordPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I know the OK button should probably have a handler, but right now this code doesn't really do anything, but I want to display the output of the text field through a println. This is really just a test app for me to learn Swift and some new API stuff.

Comment: You want to set the `delegate` of the controller and then implement the delegate callbacks

Comment: I thought UIAlertController didn't have a delegate. It doesn't appear to be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Oh no my mistake, I confused it with `UIAlertView`. You should pass in a function to the `handler` for each button. The handler will be called when its pressed

Comment: How does the handler get access to the UITextField? The closure has a return of Void and the UITextField's scope is within the closure. The handler would represent the action of clicking OK or Cancel, I don't see how that would let me query the inputted text though.

Comment: The handler's signature is :`handler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)!)`, so the sender does get passed in. You will have to access `passwordPrompt.textFields` to get the inputted text inside that handler.

Comment: Amazing. That did it. I'm confused on reading the method signature though, how did you know it passed the sender? this swift stuff is still a tad confusing (hence why I'm trying to write this code)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I know comments have been posted to answer the question, but an answer should make the solution explicit.

```
@IBOutlet var newWordField: UITextField
func wordEntered(alert: UIAlertAction!){
    // store the new word
    self.textView2.text = deletedString + " " + self.newWordField.text
}
func addTextField(textField: UITextField!){
    // add the text field and make the result global
    textField.placeholder = "Definition"
    self.newWordField = textField
}

// display an alert
let newWordPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Enter definition", message: "Trainging the machine!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
newWordPrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(addTextField)
newWordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
newWordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: wordEntered))
presentViewController(newWordPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This displays a prompt with a text field and two action buttons. It reads the text field when done.

Comment: you can also go with a weak reference to `newWordField` `weak var newWordField: UITextField` that way you do not own the textfield as it must already be pointed strongly by the alert controller
`

Answer (score 66):

I've written up a [blog post](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example) exploring the new API. You can just capture a local variable in the closure and you're good to go.

```
var inputTextField: UITextField?
let passwordPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Password", message: "You have selected to enter your password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
passwordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
passwordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    // Now do whatever you want with inputTextField (remember to unwrap the optional)
}))
passwordPrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
    textField.placeholder = "Password"
    textField.secureTextEntry = true
    inputTextField = textField
 })

presentViewController(passwordPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That way you avoid having an unnecessary property on your view controller.

Comment: I ported this to Swift 3. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39822616/211457 If someone wants to erase my answer and add my port to this answer that'd be ok with me!

Answer (score 8):

Do this inside your closure:

```
let tf = alert.textFields[0] as UITextField
```

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/genedelisa/9bf44469c7f40772f5d1)

Comment: If you use this approach, make sure to capture `alert` as `unowned` to avoid a reference cycle, which causes a memory leak.

Comment: @AshFurrow Can you please elaborate? How do you capture `alert` as `unowned`?

Comment: Actually, if you look at Apple's UICatalog example (Swift/UICatalog/AlertControllerViewController.swift), they add a NSNotificationCenter observer for handleTextFieldTextDidChangeNotification when you configure the textfield.

Comment: Sure, that works, too. My point was only that if you access the `alert.textFields` array from within the action handler closure, you'll have a reference cycle. The documentation you need is titled "[Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)".

Comment: textFields is optional, at least in Xcode 6.2. So it should be `let tf = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField`.

Answer (score 8):

I ported [Ash Furrow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25713688/211457) to Swift 3.

```
    var inputTextField: UITextField?
    let passwordPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Password", message: "You have selected to enter your password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    passwordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    passwordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        // Now do whatever you want with inputTextField (remember to unwrap the optional)
    }))
    passwordPrompt.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        inputTextField = textField
    })

    present(passwordPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```