# how to disable the both uialertcontroller button when no input in uitext field of uialertview controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

Look out my below code.I am trying to addthe text field with uialertviewcontroller.Now when there is no input in my both text field i need to disable the both action button.How to do that ??

Please make some possible solutions.Thanks !!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474762/check-on-uialertcontroller-textfield-for-enabling-the-button I'd mark it a duplicate but it's in Swift.

Comment: try this , it will help your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298679/enable-uialertaction-of-uialertcontroller-only-after-input

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Disable the buttons initially and then once you have something in your text field re-enable them.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info"
                                  message:@"You are using UIAlertController with Actionsheet and text fields"


preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Resolving UIAlert Action for tapping OK Button");
                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"Resolving UIAlertActionController for tapping cancel button");
                             [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];
[ok setEnabled:false];

[cancel setEnabled:false];

[alert addAction:ok];
[alert addAction:cancel];
```

For adding the selector to the text field and then handling it:

```
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"iCloud ID";
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}];

- (void)textDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.text.length > 0) {
        // enable the buttons
    }
}
```

For handling textfield delegates you can go through the following posts:

- [Access input from UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172593/access-input-from-uialertcontroller)
- [Check on UIAlertController TextField for enabling the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474762/check-on-uialertcontroller-textfield-for-enabling-the-button/24476797)

Comment: I din get you the solution.What happen if my two text field empty.Then how i will set my both button as  disable.And if my both text field is fill then how can i enable my both button

Comment: As per my above question code.How can i call my text field in if statement to set enable my button

Comment: Make two class level variables for your two actions. Set these actions initially as disabled like i have done in the example above. Now set the delegate of the textfields which you have added in the action as self and implement the `UITextFieldDelegate`. Once both of your textfields have content, enable the actions using the classvariables you created.

Comment: Can you please give some example code for the uitextfield delegate to enable my button if uitext filed is fill

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474762/check-on-uialertcontroller-textfield-for-enabling-the-button/24476797

Comment: Please check out this post and if you still don't understand, let me know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172593/access-input-from-uialertcontroller

Comment: i want to enable the button if the text field is fill.Then you gave the suggestion that i need to do uidelegate method for this right ??.Thats what i have asked some example code for uitext field delegate method.I am using objective c.I am beginner.So i dont know swift

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Then if say i have two text field Like textfield1,textfield 2.Then should i need to do two selector method ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120756/discussion-between-harsh-and-mack).